# Filter JSON Data Swift

Tags: json, swift, parsing, filter, nspredicate

Want to get the array of strings for a key title from below JSON response format.
Don't want to use iteration or loop.

```
[{
        "kind": "books#volume",
        "id": "D7bKNFMXNOAC",
        "volumeInfo": {
            "title": "Apples",
                "other":"Value"
        }
 },
 {
        "kind": "books#volume",
        "id": “HGHGDKJSDKJH”,
        "volumeInfo": {
            "title": "Banana",
                "other":"Value"
        }
 },
 {
        "kind": "books#volume",
        "id": “JFHDFHKSHFD”,
        "volumeInfo": {
            "title": "Orange",
                "other":"Value"
        }
}]
```

Expecting: array-["Apples", "Banana", "Orange"].

Comment: Show us what you have tried, How you are getting this JSON.

Comment: `if let info = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data as Data){
            
            //3. Pick out all the Items from response
            let arrayAllRecords = (info as? NSDictionary)?.object(forKey: "items") as! NSArray
            //4. Filter all volumeInfo Dictioanry
            let arrayVolumeInfo = arrayAllRecords.mutableArrayValue(forKey: "volumeInfo")
            //5. Filter to get all titles
            titles = arrayVolumeInfo.mutableArrayValue(forKey: "title")
}`

Answer (score 1):

Please see the below example. You can get array of 'titles' using `flatMap` func.

```
let json = [
        [
            "kind": "books#volume",
            "id": "D7bKNFMXNOAC",
            "volumeInfo": [
                "title": "Apples",
                "other":"Value"
            ]
        ],
        [
            "kind": "books#volume",
            "id": "HGHGDKJSDKJH",
            "volumeInfo": [
                "title": "Banana",
                "other":"Value"
            ]
        ],
        [
            "kind": "books#volume",
            "id": "JFHDFHKSHFD",
            "volumeInfo": [
                "title": "Orange",
                "other":"Value"
            ]
        ]
    ]

    let titles = json.flatMap { ($0["volumeInfo"] as! [String : Any])["title"] }
    print(titles)   //["Apples", "Banana", "Orange"]
```

Comment: Thanks, Bhautik,
Below also work for me.
`//4. Filter all volumeInfo Dictioanry
            let arrayVolumeInfo = arrayAllRecords.mutableArrayValue(forKey: "volumeInfo")
            //5. Filter to get all titles
            titles = arrayVolumeInfo.mutableArrayValue(forKey: "title")`